# Rule to travel with a passport with less than 6 months validity

Tags: visas, passports, germany, regulations

I am an Indian national with Indian passport.

I am a Blue card (long term visa) holder in Germany. My passport is valid till August and I have to go to India for one week in mid-April. Therefore, I do not have enough time to apply for a new passport and a new blue card.

I heard that I cannot enter Germany again with the passport of less than 6 months validity (not sure about this info).

Please tell me if is it possible to get some document (from Indian Embassy in Germany or German Visa Office) which says that I am permitted to enter again...or something else ***which permits me to enter Germany with a passport having validity 3.5 months***

> **UPDATE:**
>   My blue card is valid till August because my passport is also valid till August. The visa officer told me that a new blue card will be issued with the renewed passport. It is because the blue card has your passport number and therefore, new passport->new number->so new blue card.

Comment: Please check the update.

Comment: Most countries allow you to keep the old passport even after you have a new one, of course with markings that make it obsolete, like a corner cut off or a stamp inside. Make sure to keep your old passport, and with both the new and old passport, the blue card should be still valid till the last day.

Comment: @user2756695, I've removed my comment, I didn't know about the validity of the *card*. I'd suggest to ask the Ausländerbehörde of your city or county. Perhaps someone at your company can help you write the letter -- if you have a blue card, Germany *wants* you to stay ...

Comment: Generally in Schengen countries there is a requirement that a visitor's passport be valid at least 3 months beyond the intended date of departure. Since you are a resident, you don't intend to depart. I expect you can enter up until the expiration date of your residence permit (blue card) as long as your passport is valid on the day of entry. As this concerns a long-term residence, you're more likely to get a useful answer at http://expatriates.stackexchange.com.